# Style css dynamically generated?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have this site:

http://avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

On this site footer appears in a black who wish to delete

To solve this problem I need to change the height of this line of code

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 126px;" id="footer-sidebar" class="footer-sidebar widget-area masonry" role="complementary"
```

My problem is that I can not find the file to be edited ... I searched everywhere

We found the same time and where told this code in footer.php ...

This is code footer.php

```
<div id="supplementary">
<div id="footer-sidebar" class="footer-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ); ?>
</div><!-- #footer-sidebar -->
```

The 2825 line is found CSS code but can not change the height:

```
  .site-footer {
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
}
```

They are all information available at this time ... please can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a quick script:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', updateAttribute);

function updateAttribute() {
  document.getElementById('footer-sidebar').setAttribute('style','position:relative;');
}
</script>
```

This would remove the `height:126px;` part that is added dynamicaly.

OR

Set height in the CSS code:

```
.site-footer {
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: And how do I add such a script?
I've never done ... an example would help

Comment: @Mihaiandrei Right at the end of your html right before the `</body>` tag paste the `<script>` block above exactly as is (including the <script>) into your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to get rid of the black section, just change the line

```
background-color: #000;
```

to

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: Yes, but what I did and I like to do everything to get down menu below to cover myself this space ...